# Why is using this import breaking my module?

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

Why am I getting an error saying my function is undefined when I import a module?

I have a simple JavaScript module and whenever I import ethers, my functions display as no longer defined.

Before importing ethers

```html
<button type="button" onclick="run();">Run my stuff</button>

<script type="module">
  function run() { 
      console.log("Hello world!") 
  } 
  window.run = run;
</script>
```

After importing ethers

```html
<button type="button" onclick="run();">Run my stuff</button>

<script type="module">
  import { ethers } from "https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.esm.min.js";
  
  function run() { 
      console.log("Hello world!") 
  } 
  window.run = run;
</script>
```

Why is this happening?